Configuring gitlab-ci to push to Azure Container Registry using Docker image
The problem is that when the code is on GitLab, it says, No related tags found.
Here is my gitlab-ci.yml file. All of the variables are stored in the GitLab CI/CD variables.
stages:
  - build
  - push
  - deploy

variables:
  TAG: $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
  PROJECT_NAME: project-name

build:
  stage: build
  image: docker:20.10.16
  services:
    - docker:20.10.16-dind
  tags:
    - docker
  before_script:
    - docker login $ACR_LOGIN_SERVER -u $ACR_USERNAME -p $ACR_PASSWORD
  script:
    - docker build --pull --rm -f "backend/Dockerfile" -t webapi:$TAG "im_v2/backend"
    - docker build --pull --rm -f "frontend/Dockerfile" -t client:$TAG "im_v2/frontend"
    - docker build --pull --rm -f "deploy/gateway/Dockerfile" -t gateway:$TAG "im_v2/deploy/gateway"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - deploy/production/docker-compose.yml
  only:
    - /^development.*$/
    - /^deployment.*$/

push:
  stage: push
  image: docker:20.10.16
  services:
    - docker:20.10.16-dind
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    - docker push webapi:$TAG
    - docker push client:$TAG
    - docker push gateway:$TAG
  only:
    - /^development.*$/
    - /^deployment.*$/

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli
  script:
    - az login --service-principal --username $AZURE_CLIENT_ID --password $AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET --tenant $AZURE_TENANT_ID
    - az webapp config container set --name $AZURE_APP_SERVICE_NAME --resource-group $AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP --multicontainer-config-type compose --multicontainer-config-file deploy/production/docker-compose.yml
  when: manual
  environment:
    name: production
    url: https://$AZURE_APP_SERVICE_NAME.azurewebsites.net
  only:
    - /^development.*$/
    - /^deployment.*$/

I am just trying to create CI/CD pipeline and make it work.
I tried different ways, but none of them worked.

If this gitlab instance is self hosted, you need to check, if you assigned the tag "docker" to one of the runners.

The tag "docker" is assigned to several runners. And the gitlab instance is self hosted.

You need to put your docker build and docker push steps in the same job. Otherwise, in most runner setups, your 'push' job may run on a different host where the image was never built. Additionally, you should be tagging/pushing your images using the fully qualified name and path to the image, including the domain of your ACR registry.

I have done few changes in the yml at login and build stage .
I followed this documentation and so link to build and push container images to a container registry in GitLab.Thanks @yamenk for the explanation.
image: docker:20.10.16

services:
  - docker:20.10.16-dind

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2376
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  CONTAINER_IMAGE: $ACR_LOGIN_SERVER/samples/nginx:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG

stages:
  - login
  - build
  - push

login:
  stage: login
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache curl jq
    - az login --service-principal -u $AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID -p $AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_PASSWORD --tenant $AZURE_TENANT_ID
    - az acr login --name $ACR_NAME

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker pull nginx
    - docker tag nginx $CONTAINER_IMAGE
    - docker build -t $CONTAINER_IMAGE .
    - docker images

push:
  stage: push
  script:
    - echo "Pushing image to ACR..."
    - docker push $CONTAINER_IMAGE
  only:
    - main
# optional
cleanup:
  stage: cleanup
  script:
    - docker rmi $CONTAINER_IMAGE
    - az acr repository delete --name $ACR_NAME --image samples/nginx:latest
  when: manual



If you are using Azure Container Registry with a username and password, you can log in to  Registry as shown below:
docker login $ACR_LOGIN_SERVER -u $ACR_USERNAME -p $ACR_PASSWORD


Output:


